# ORA-00904: "Good Resort": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, case, ora-00904

I have created the following select query to display data based on if then else using `CASE-WHEN-THEN`

```
select id,name,
    case
     when rating between 4.0 and 5 then "very good"
     when rating between 3.0 and 3.5 the "good"
    else "Good Resort"
    end as comment
from resort
order by id;
```

when executed it gives this

error

> **ORA-00904**: "Good Resort": invalid identifier

Comment: Enclose strings in single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes. Double quotes get interpreted as a field:

```
select id,name,
    case
     when rating between 4.0 and 5 then 'very good'
     when rating between 3.0 and 3.5 then 'good'
    else 'Good Resort'
    end as comment
from resort
order by id;
```